# How to measure dB in terms of factor?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, acoustics

We know that,

- 3 dB means factor of 2.
- 10 dB means factor of 10.

By using this information, I want to calculate 1 dB to 10 dB in terms of factor.

What could be the approach?

Till now, my conclusion is like below.

- 1 dB means factor of __.
- 2 dB means factor of __.
- 3 dB means factor of 2.
- 4 dB means factor of __.
- 5 dB means factor of __.
- 6 dB means factor of 4.
- 7 dB means factor of __.
- 8 dB means factor of __.
- 9 dB means factor of 8.
- 10 dB means factor of 10.

So, how could I find the rest?

Comment: It is a logarithmic scale. And always be careful if you are applying it to voltage or power!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, as you show, the decibel scale is a scale used to ***compare*** two levels: the one you're measuring, and another value.  The definition of the decibel scale is:$$dB = 10 \times \log_{10} \left( \frac{I}{I_{Ref}} \right)$$where $I$ is the signal/sound/power that you want to measure, and $I_{Ref}$ is the value you want to compare it to. (If you want $bel$ units, just leave out the factor of $10$.)

To fill out the table you've started. you need to reverse this calculation to find  $\frac{I}{I_{Ref}} $

1. Take the particular dB you want to convert ------- say $3\text{ dB}$
2. Divide by $10$------------------------------------------------$0.3\text{ Bel}$
3. Use a calculator to raise the logarithm base, $10$, to the power of the $\text{Bel}$ level$$\text{Factor}=10^{0.3}=1.99526\approx2.00$$